# Запуск swagger_server через uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, swagger, uwsgi, wsgi

Мой сгенерированный swagger_server отлично работает при запуске с:
`python3 -m swagger_server`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import connexion

from swagger_server import encoder


def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
    app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'API'}, pythonic_params=True)
    app.run(port=8080)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу найти синтаксис для вызова wsgi.py сервера swagger_server, поскольку он был построен как модуль.

Возникла такая проблема, помогите пожалуйста написать `wsgi.py`

P.S. если вам нужна еще какая-то дополнительная информация для решения этой проблемы, напишите я предоставлю.

**UPD.
Решение:**
Поменял `__main__.py` на:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import connexion

from swagger_server import encoder



app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'API'}, pythonic_params=True)
application = app.app
```

и добавил `wsgi.py` в корневую папку:

```
from swagger_server.__main__ import application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Запустил через команду `uwsgi --http-socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file wsgi.py --callable application --processes 4 --threads 2`

Comment: Насколько много Вы используете swagger? У Вас уже большой проект?

Comment: @hedgehogues нет проект не большой, вы хотели что то поменять?

Comment: возможно, имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону fastapi. Там сваггер и uvicorn идут из коробки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connexion.App не имеет интерфейса wsgi.

Можно вытащить aiohttp( или flask) приложение по ссылке

```
aioapp = app.app
```

А дальше оборачивать это в wsgi

Comment: Ваш комментарий мне помог.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из решений -- отказ от flask в пользу [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/). Затраты на переход минимальные. В замен Вы получите из коробки:

- uvicorn
- swagger
- pydantic

Пример

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Optional[str] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

Запуск

```
uvicorn main:app --reload --workers=5 --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]